# Is Arellano-Bond estimator applicable?

Tags: panel-data

I consider the model

$$y_{it} = \rho y_{it-1} + X_i\beta + \alpha_i + u_{it},$$

where $\alpha_i$ are unobservable individual effects. I am interested in estimation of $\rho$, while other coefficients are of a bit lesser interest.

1. Is this model the right choice if I am interested primarily in $\rho$?
2. Is Arellano-Bond estimator applicable to this model? (my $X_i$ do not vary in time as in classic dynamic panel model).

If no, what can I use instead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When $X_i$ is not time-varying, you may redefine
$$
\alpha_i=X_i\beta + \alpha_i
$$
to obtain the baseline Arellano-Bond model
$$y_{it} = \rho y_{it-1} + \alpha_i + u_{it},$$
in which you can use the corresponding estimator provided the other assumptions (e.g., no serial correlation in $u_{it}$) are met.